# Rspec case for rails 4 patch :update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Devise in my app, and trying to write a spec for updating email ID. The UI works, but the spec is failing. I am reloading the user object as well, before testing against changed email ID.

One thing that I do observe is that there is UPDATE USERS statement being run on the database.

What is the correct way to write the spec?

RSpec spec:

```
it "should update email" do
  @user = subject.current_user
  patch :update, id: @user, user: {:email => "john.doe@example1.com"}
  @user.reload
  expect(@user.email).to eq("john.doe@example1.com")
end
```

RSpec Error Log:

```
1) Users::RegistrationsController logged in user should update email
   Failure/Error: expect(@user.email).to eq("john.doe@example1.com")

   expected: "john.doe@example1.com"
        got: "john.doe@example.com"

   (compared using ==)
```

test.log:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  User Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'john.doe@example.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (4.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "last_name", "updated_at")     VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 22 Jun 2013 13:12:28 UTC +00:00], ["email", "john.doe@example.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$04$LIRWzphxstpCLTuZjicA..YMW.Ei2V/LlYWP32gfx39nBjhFg5tLe"], ["first_name", "John"], ["last_name", "Doe"], ["updated_at", Sat, 22 Jun 2013 13:12:28 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 457 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"457", "user"=>{"email"=>"john.doe@example1.com"}}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 457]]
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'john.doe@example1.com' AND "users"."id" !=     457) LIMIT 1
  Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.slim within layouts/application (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 73ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 457]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
it "should update email" do
  @user = subject.current_user
  patch :update, id: @user, user: {:email => "john.doe@example1.com"}
  @user.reload.email.should == "john.doe@example1.com"
end
```

Or alternatively

```
it "should update email" do
  @user = subject.current_user
  expect {
    patch :update, id: @user, user: {:email => "john.doe@example1.com"}
    @user.reload
  }.to change(@user, :email).to("john.doe@example1.com")
end
```

Comment: After looking at your test.log you posted it looks like email isn't being passed as a param `Parameters: {"id"=>"424", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Jane"}}` although that could just be from another action that was done in your test.

Comment: Oops, sorry, wrong test log snippet. I have updated the correct one now.

Comment: What do your validations for your User model look like?

Comment: Only those provided by Devise (3.0.0.rc). Take a look here: https://gist.github.com/subhashb/5843734